# JMeter MongoDB Where Clause NOT Working with $gt $lt

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter, java

I am getting below error, when I try to use greater than or less than in mongoDB where clause: Any idea how to avoid this?

```
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: gt for class: Script117
```

Below is my Full Groovy Code till now:
Everything works except the GREATER THAN (or lt) query filter:

```
import com.mongodb.DB;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoDBHolder;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.*;
//======================================================================
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("${serverIP}", ${serverPort}));
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("${mongodb}");
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("${collectionName}");

StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();
rs.append("Collection: \n");

BasicDBObject allQuery = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
fields.put("name", 1);     //projected fields
fields.put("age", 1);      //projected fields
fields.put("eyeColor", 1); //projected fields
fields.put("balance", 1);  //projected fields
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
//whereQuery.put("gender", "female");
whereQuery.put("age", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 30));

DBCursor cursor = coll.find(whereQuery, fields);
while( cursor.hasNext() )  {
        DBObject obj = cursor.next();
        rs.append(obj.toString());
        rs.append("\n");
}
rs.toString();
//String variable at the LAST LINE of this Groovy script will be displayed in Results tab, even if no Display methods are invoked !!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be avoiding:

- Referring JMeter Variables as `${var}`
- Using `$var` structures

as they have special meaning in Groovy, so:

1. Replace these `${serverIP}` with `vars.get("serverIP")`, `${mongodb}` with `vars.get("mongodb")`, etc.
2. Replace double quotes with single quotes, especially in the line where you use `$gt` function
3. (Optional) semicolons at the lines end are not necessary

References:

- [Groovy Differences with Java](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html)
- [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter)

Answer (score 2):

The error message: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException, is thrown when:

> An exception occurred while a dynamic property dispatch fails with an
>   unknown property.

**Note**: the **Missing*Exception** classes are named for consistency and to avoid conflicts with JDK exceptions of the same name.

The attempt to insert the "age" as key and the new BasicDBObject("$gt",30) as a value, cause to the exception you get, because the JVM looks for a property calls gt which is not exists.

The put method means: Sets a name/value pair in this object.
In the code you have you intend to append the search criteria, and not to put it.

Related to the code you have, I would recommend replacing the using of **put** method with **append**.

This is your code:

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
//whereQuery.put("gender", "female");
whereQuery.put("age", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 30));
```

If you replace the:

```
whereQuery.put("age", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 30));
```

With:

```
whereQuery.append("age", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 30));
```

Another suggestion you can use is the **Criteria.where** syntax,
which is much more readable.

```
def query = Query.query(Criteria.where('gender').is('female').and('age')
            .gt(30))
collection.find(query, fields)
```

Another small issue, because your code is written in Groovy you should not finish each line with ;

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using single quotes so groovy doesn't think you're doing string templating?

```
whereQuery.put("age", new BasicDBObject('$gt', 30))
//                                      ^   ^ here
```